# SQL Server 2008 query to convert column values to different columns dynamically

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table like below:

```
panelistId  DTTM
337322  7/27/2014 19:39
337322  7/27/2014 19:29
317420  7/27/2014 10:22
317420  7/27/2014 10:22
317420  7/27/2014 9:27
336333  7/27/2014 5:41
336333  7/27/2014 3:26
336333  7/27/2014 3:26
336333  7/27/2014 1:25
```

I am looking for a SQL select query to have below fields from this table:

```
panelistId | #ofExposures | Exposure_DTTM1 | Exposure_DTTM2 | Exposure_DTTM3 |  Exposure_DTTM4 | Exposure_DTTM5 | etc
337322 | 2 | 7/27/2014 19:39 | 7/27/2014 19:29 |  |  |
```

Here number of DTTM will be different for each id. If an id will have only 3 DTTM then for rest of the DTTM columns it can be blank.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: You are looking for `count(*) group by panelistId` and then `pivot`

Comment: I am looking for something like "data in a singular row per respondent" for more analysis on data

Comment: What you are looking for is a crosstab and there are at least a million explanations on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. Hope it helps

```
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (RowID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
                   panelistId INT ,
                   #ofExposures VARCHAR(MAX),
                   Exposure_DTTMVARCHAR(MAX))

DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT ,
                  DTTM VARCHAR(30)) INSERT INTO @Table (ID,
                DTTM) VALUES ('337322', '7/27/2014 19:39'), ('337322', '7/27/2014 19:29'), ('317420', '7/27/2014 10:22'), ('317420', '7/27/2014 10:22'), ('317420', '7/27/2014 9:27'), ('336333', '7/27/2014 5:41'), ('336333', '7/27/2014 3:26'), ('336333', '7/27/2014 3:26'), ('336333', '7/27/2014 1:25'); WITH cte_StageOne
    AS (

    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY CAST(t.DTTM AS DATETIME) ) AS OrderID,         *
    FROM @Table AS t
    )
    INSERT INTO @Table2
    SELECT  MAX(ID)  AS panelistId,
          MAX(OrderID) AS #ofExposures,
          STUFF((
               SELECT  ' | ' + cso.DTTM
               FROM cte_StageOne AS cso
               WHERE ocso.ID = cso.ID
               FOR XML PATH('')
               ), 1, 3, '') AS #Exposure
    FROM cte_StageOne AS ocso
    GROUP BY ID

--SELECT * FROM @Table2

DECLARE @MaxDTTM INT DECLARE @StartLoop INT DECLARE @EndLoop INT DECLARE @ColumnList VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @MaxDTTM = MAX(#ofExposures),
       @EndLoop = MAX(RowID),
       @StartLoop = MIN(RowID) FROM @Table2

SET @ColumnList = 'panelistId|#ofExposures|Exposure_DTTM1'

WHILE @StartLoop <= @EndLoop
    BEGIN
       SET @ColumnList = @ColumnList + '|Exposure_DTTM' + CAST(@StartLoop + 1 AS VARCHAR(3))

       SET @StartLoop = @StartLoop + 1
    END SET @ColumnList = @ColumnList

SET @StartLoop = 1

WHILE @StartLoop <= @EndLoop
    BEGIN
       DECLARE @in_panelistId VARCHAR(10)
       DECLARE @in_ofExposures VARCHAR(10)
       DECLARE @in_Exposure_DTTM VARCHAR(MAX)

       SELECT  @in_panelistId = panelistId,
             @in_ofExposures = #ofExposures,
             @in_Exposure_DTTM = Exposure_DTTM
       FROM @Table2
       WHERE RowID = @StartLoop

       SET @ColumnList = @ColumnList + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + @in_panelistId + '|' + @in_ofExposures + '|' + @in_Exposure_DTTM + REPLICATE('|', @MaxDTTM - @in_ofExposures)

       --PRINT REPLICATE('|',@MaxDTTM - @in_ofExposures)

       SET @StartLoop = @StartLoop + 1
    END PRINT @ColumnList
```

Comment: This will not fully solve my requirement.<br>
I am looking for a result like:<br>

panelistId | #ofExposures | Exposure_DTTM1 | Exposure_DTTM2 | Exposure_DTTM3 |  Exposure_DTTM4 | Exposure_DTTM5 | etc<br>
337322 | 2 | 7/27/2014 19:39 | 7/27/2014 19:29 |  |  |  <br>
317420 | 3 | 7/27/2014 10:22 | 7/27/2014 10:22 | 7/27/2014 9:27 |  |  <br>
336333 | 4 | 7/27/2014 5:41 | 7/27/2014 3:26 | 7/27/2014 3:26 | 7/27/2014 1:25 |

Comment: @Anoop so do u need pipe delimited with everything in one line?

Comment: @Anoop Made the changes as requested, Please verify and hope it helps.